# ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException for a Media Player - how are we supposed to handle Foreground Service and AudioFocus in Android 12?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, foreground-service

In Android 12 I play music using `MediaPlayer` and `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`.

1. Playback is ongoing, Service is in Foreground
2. Taking a call, Service looses AudioFocus so it pauses and exits Foreground
3. Ending call, Service re-gains AudioFocus, so it resumes playback and enters Foreground again

At this point I am getting the exception:

`android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.music.player/PlayerService`

Sure, but the behaviour described is just what the [Media App documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview) says to do. So following their rules, results in a crash if I compile for API 31 and run on Android 12.

So how are we supposed to implement this flow on Android 12 then?

Comment: The documentation that you linked to says nothing about changing the foreground status of the service. If your intention is to resume the music when the call ends, you cannot revoke your foreground status -- partly, because of the problem you are encountering, and partly because if the call lasts for more than a minute your service is going to be destroyed (on Android 8.0+).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yet somehow YouTube Music is able to stopForeground when the call comes in and then enter foreground and start playing music again when the call ends. As far as I know they target Android 13. Are they cheating?

Comment: @SteveM "YouTube Music is able to stopForeground when the call comes in" -- how have you determined this? "As far as I know they target Android 13" -- how have you determined this? "Are they cheating?" -- we cannot rule that out.

Comment: @CommonsWare You can swipe away the media controls notification when you're on the call, I don't think there would be another way to allow that. I used aapt to verify it does indeed target 33.

Comment: @SteveM: "You can swipe away the media controls notification when you're on the call, I don't think there would be another way to allow that" -- last I checked, that's not strictly tied to `startForeground()`. That at least used to be tied to `FLAG_ONGOING` on the `Notification`. "I used aapt to verify it does indeed target 33" -- OK, that's pretty definitive, thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried set `setOngoing(false)` on a notification in a foreground service and it can't be dismissed despite the flag..guess they're cheating.

Comment: @CommonsWare After further experimenting it is possible for a third party app to have the same behavior as YT Music (having a dismissible notification with a foreground service in a media app). Something to do with the PlaybackState that is set on the MediaSession, I actually think it's a bit of a bug

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to not `stopForeground()` in `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT`. We may gain audio focus again and need to start playing, so don't drop foreground status here.

Comment: It's strange and super confusing. How are Spotify and others are able to stopForeground and then resume playback by startForeground all while in the background. We are missing something or it is not documented well .